# Laravel queue rate limiting not executing work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I'm attempting to implement [Laravel 5.7's queue job rate limiting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#rate-limiting) which for use when queue jobs hit an external API that's rate limited.

Here's my job:

```
    public function handle() {
        echo 'about to check throttling'.PHP_EOL;
        Redis::throttle('throttle-test')->allow(10)->every(5)->then(function () {
            // this is never executed
            echo 'doing work'.PHP_EOL;
        }, function () {
            // also never executed
            echo 'released back onto queue'.PHP_EOL;
            return $this->release(10);
        });
    }
```

There's no mention of needing to use Redis for queues, cache or anything of that nature in the docs, aside from "...application can interact with a Redis server."  Either way, here's my env vars:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIS_HOST=redis
```

I've confirmed the `RedisServiceProvider` is receiving the correct configuration it expects:

```
array:3 [
  "client" => "predis"
  "default" => array:4 [
    "host" => "redis"
    "password" => null
    "port" => "6379"
    "database" => 0
  ]
  "horizon" => array:5 [
    "host" => "redis"
    "password" => null
    "port" => "6379"
    "database" => 0
    "options" => array:1 [
      "prefix" => "horizon:"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I'm struggling to understand why there's no runtime errors, it's just that nothings get executed.  If I comment out the throttle stuff the job runs fine and does what it's supposed to do.  **What am I missing about the requirements to use this throttling?**

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` last lines, Queue generally failed silently but written to Log when errors occured.

Comment: Check `storage/loogs/laravel.log` last lines, Queue generally failed silently but written to Log when errors occured.

Comment: The main issue I always have with anything queue related in Laravel is that debugging is a pain. You can always `Log::info()` rather than `echo` but generally checking the logfile is the only way to find out what's going on.

Comment: With my queue driver being "sync" it's all being executed in the current process and not queued so an `echo` should be sufficient.  My logs go to stdout anyways and I'm not seeing anything there.

Comment: In Laravel Docs it says that `Rate Limiting. This feature requires that your application can interact with a Redis server.` So since you're using  `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`, your queue never get handled by Redis, so it would never be executed. Rate Limiting is a REDIS-ONLY feature.

Comment: `interact with a Redis server` and `using redis as your queue` are 2 different things.  I think it would specify a queue if it required Redis being used as a queue.  I've confirmed the Redis store information is correctly being passed to the `RedisServiceProvider`

Comment: are you using supervisor for queues ?

Comment: I'm deployed using Docker, queues are managed via Laravel Horizon.

Comment: Does `redis` actually resolve through DNS to your redis host? I'm not completely familiar with how docker handles internal networking in this regard, but including some of your Dockerfile might help. Also, I know it's been mentioned already but would you try changing your `echo` statements to `logger()->debug('starting/working/released')`? Even if using the sync driver *should* be enough for echo statements to appear, it would just help us completely rule out that possibility.

Comment: Yes, it does resolve as other elements with my app (such as caching) rely on it.

Comment: Have you attempted to use `redis` as the queue driver in your `.env` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for Laravel in this case is very misleading.  While it implies you only need a connection to `Redis` you actually have to be using `Redis` for your queues.

Comment: No! You don't need to use redis for your queue if you use the rate limiters. This answer is not correct!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no "official" way to rate limit queue without using `Redis` queue driver.

I wrote custom queue worker [mxl/laravel-queue-rate-limit](https://github.com/mxl/laravel-queue-rate-limit) that uses `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter` to rate limit job execution (the same one that used internally by Laravel to [rate limit HTTP requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#rate-limiting)).

Read more about its usage on [GitHub page](https://github.com/mxl/laravel-queue-rate-limit) or in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57329506/746347).